# Compare key items in a list not a dictionary that are same in order to calculate those same line items for a final result

Tags: python, excel, list, compare

The way this list came to life was from an excel document I created that sheet 1 has channel numbers and sheet 2 has wattage values for if channel is in between a low and highValue. In trying to keep a list with exact placement of where it is in correlation to the excel document. The only way i could find was to take from a for statement and append it as a line number in the results below. Which happens to be the watts that came from the channel numbers. I am new to python, new to posting here please bear with me if I screw up getting to code to post correctly. I remember from the last time I screwed up plenty.

```
[0, 1225, 1, 160, 1, 160, 1, 160, 1, 160, 1, 350, 1, 350, 1, 350, 1, 350, 2, 870, 2, 870, 3, 582, 3, 582, 3, 582, 3, 582, 3, 582, 4, 161, 4, 161, 4, 161, 4, 161, 4, 161, 5, 1225, 6, 870, 6, 870, 7, 1225, 8, 582, 8, 582, 8, 582, 8, 582, 9, 160, 9, 160, 9, 160, 10, 161, 10, 161, 10, 161, 10, 161, 10, 161, 11, 1225, 12, 870, 12, 870, 13, 582, 13, 582, 13, 582, 13, 582, 13, 582, 14, 160, 14, 160, 14, 160, 15, 161, 15, 161, 15, 161, 15, 161, 15, 161, 16, 1225, 17, 1225, 18, 1225, 18, 1225, 19, 160, 19, 160, 19, 160, 19, 350, 19, 350, 19, 350, 19, 350, 20, 160, 20, 870, 20, 870, 21, 582, 21, 582, 21, 582, 21, 582, 21, 582, 22, 161, 22, 161, 22, 161, 22, 161, 22, 161, 24, 870, 24, 1225, 25, 870, 25, 1225, 26, 582, 26, 582, 26, 582, 26, 582, 27, 160, 27, 160, 27, 160, 28, 161, 28, 161, 28, 161, 28, 161, 28, 161, 30, 870, 30, 870, 31, 582, 31, 582, 31, 582, 31, 582, 31, 582, 32, 160, 32, 160, 32, 160, 33, 161, 33, 161, 33, 161, 33, 161, 33, 161, 34, 1225, 34, 1225, 37, 900, 37, 900, 38, 900, 38, 900, 39, 820, 41, 820, 41, 900, 42, 900, 42, 900, 44, 820, 44, 900, 47, 900, 47, 900]
```

as you notice that this is just a list. If you have a way that i could have created a dictionary with the findings I would love to hear it. I used Pandas to get the comparisons that gave me the list above. My next step is as you notice before the 3 digit numbers is a number which reflects being on the same line from the excel file. As you see 1 has 160 and 350 values. I am stuck figuring out a loop to iterate through the list, to say if value is 1 then totalWatts += 160 += 350 etc.. etc.. which at each line will append another list the total watts of that line. I am not sure if pandas is the best option for this or if there is another option that is better. The answer to line one would be totalLineWatts.append(totalWatts) which will give me a list that I will take to oop to calculate amps of that line in the excel which the total is 2040.  Which I can see i will have too do another append before the totalWatts with the number because some lines are missing, the reason for this is that line has no channels in the excel doc. So if anybody can show me an example of the way to get past this step it will be very much appreciated.

Adding some working code from a version that was not OOP. But only allowed 5 channels. I am creating one that allow unlimited channels per circuit. But in counting those is what I am trying to solve with the above question. Take a look at a working code that only counts 5 of the channel line.

```
counter3 = 0
channelNums3 = []
thirdRowWatts = 0
thirdLineAmps = []
thirdVolts = wattSheet['Voltage'][2]
thirdActualWatts = []
thirdSection = []

for h in range(27, 33, 1):
    for j in range(4, 9, 1):
        channelNums3.append(df.loc[h, j])
        thirdSection = channelNums3[:5]

    for e in range(5):
        f = thirdSection[e]
        for g in range(rowCount - 2):
            thirdChanLow = wattSheet['ChanLow'][g]
            thirdChanHi = wattSheet['ChanHigh'][g]
            if f in range(thirdChanLow, thirdChanHi):
                thirdWatts = wattSheet['Wattage'][g]
                thirdRowWatts += thirdWatts
    thirdLineAmps.append(round((thirdRowWatts/thirdVolts/2), 2))  # gets my amps per leg
    thirdActualWatts.append(thirdRowWatts)
    print(thirdSection)
    print(f"Actual watts this circuit is {thirdActualWatts[-1]}") # this circuits total watts
    print(f"Total Watts: {thirdRowWatts} / Voltage {thirdVolts} / 2 legs = {thirdLineAmps[-1]}")
    print(thirdLineAmps)
    thirdRowWatts = 0  # resets thirdRowWatts variable for the next circuit check.
    channelNums3 = []  # resets list so the slice works
# TODO Below is the inserting into the excel Document for the 3rd section Backed up to github as 3rd working
# example sheet2.range("C4", "D4").value = lineAmps[0]
sheet2.range("C29", "D29").value = thirdLineAmps[0]
sheet2.range("D30", "E30").value = thirdLineAmps[1]
sheet2.range("C31").value = thirdLineAmps[2]
sheet2.range("E31").value = thirdLineAmps[2]
sheet2.range("C32", "D32").value = thirdLineAmps[3]
sheet2.range("D33", "E33").value = thirdLineAmps[4]
sheet2.range("C34").value = thirdLineAmps[5]
sheet2.range("E34").value = thirdLineAmps[5]
```

That code counts for 6 circuits at 5 channels. The code that can count unlimited channels can count unlimited channels. I am just having a hard time calculating the total watts for one line. without counting watts for others hence the above first code of 1's = 2040.
Thanks
Something about im cannot answer because of a bad question. So i am editing the first to post my work around to get me the calculations of the rows that I wanted at the top.

```
circTotalWatts1 = []
class CircWatts:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.rackSize = 48
        self.circTotalWatts = []
        
    def circuitWatts(self, dfWatts):
        for x in range(self.rackSize):
            lineTotal = int(dfWatts.iloc[x].sum())
            circTotalWatts1.append(lineTotal)
        self.circTotalWatts = pd.DataFrame(circTotalWatts1)
            
        return self.circTotalWatts
```

I know it doesnt make sense without the main.py Yet I know there had to be a way to calculate that row and seperate the nan rows. Hope this gets me out of trouble with stackOverflow.

Comment: Okay, you showed us a list that will be input to the program. **Exactly what result should you get, for this input?** According to what logic? Please read [ask] and be precise. Think clearly about what you want to write before writing it. Keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**; do not give us a stream of thought. [You are expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to do that planning and thinking **before** posting a question.

Comment: There was planning and thinking and about a day of researching iterating examples, to get to asking the question.  I am asking how to iterate through the list and extract the values of the number after what would be considered the key. Notice 0, 1, 2 in the list. There are multiple on some lines and none on others. I need to add the number behind it together for the "key" notice the 1's added up are 2040.

Comment: " I need to add the number behind it together for the "key" notice the 1's added up are 2040." --> there is *40 channel* in ur given list...    | But the for loop in ur code indicate `range(27, 33, 1)` & `range(4, 9, 1)`... plus the "That code counts for 6 circuits at 5 channels" comment..  seems to describe a _different_ list from the one given. Mind to clarify ?

Comment: @ p._phidot_ Because that is a section of the Excel. After it handles the 6 circuits and 6 channels from watts it has to do amp calculation's then show the results on the excel. Which eats up some lines then goes on to another 6 circuits and 5 channels. The entire reason this project started what recently had a gig where i needed to add more then 5 channels in 1 circuit. Which was becoming a problem for my original script to handle. The new one has about 5 scripts controlled by one main.py. If i could add this photo it would be easy to show.

Answer (score 0):

The question was tagged excel but the code provided are in python. Without sample excel files/complete a way to reproduce the case, I'd might as well just share an alternative way to get to the results. Using excel. Hope it suffice.

Assuming the data in the list is located at A1:A245. Do:

- In cell B1 put   `=COUNT(A:A)`
- In cell C1 put   `=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(D:D,D:D)>0))`
- In cell D1 put   `=IF(ROW()>$B$1/2,"",INDIRECT("A"&((ROW()-1)*2+1)))`
- In cell E1 put   `=IF(ROW()>$B$1/2,"",INDIRECT("A"&((ROW()-1)*2+2)))`
- In cell F1 put
  `=IF(ROW()>$B$1/2,"",IF(ROW()=1,1,IF(ROW()>$B$1,"",IF(OFFSET(D2,-1,0)<>OFFSET(D2,-2,0),OFFSET(F2,-2,0)+1,OFFSET(F2,-2,0)))))`
- In cell G1 put
  `=IF(ROW()>MAX(F:F),"",INDEX(D:D,MATCH(ROW(),F:F,0)))`
- In cell H1 put   `=IF(ROW()>MAX(F:F),"",SUMIF(D:D,G1,E:E))`

Then select D1:H1, drag them downwards. Done.

You'd get column G as ur unique channel list, & column H is its individual sum.

Idea :

- B1 value is used to 'stop' output for column D,E,F .
- C1 value is used to 'stop' output for column G,H,I .
- Column G:H will be the "total watts of that line" requested.

Note : I intentionally didn't use FILTER() function so that this will work on non-365 excel.

Comment: I like your thinking through with the if row = 1 and I can see it working nicely. this was a project i thought up to use python to take from excel and  do some calcs then put back different results. If i could add a picture to this reply it would make it easier to see what I was after. Thank you for your time in doing this.